# matrix in object datatype python

Tags: python, object, matrix, types

Can you pls explain how to create a matrix in python to be created in object datatype. My code :

```
w, h = 8, 5;
Matrix = ([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)],dtype=object)
```

gives a syntax error. I tried various other ways. But still none of them working.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Everything is object in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the Matrix line tries to create a tuple, however you are giving it an expression `dtype=object`.

```
Matrix = ([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)],dtype=object)
```

The line reads: Set matrix to the tuple `(2D array, dtype=object)`. However, the second part cannot be set. You can create the matrix as follows:

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

Or if you would like to have a numpy array with dtype object:

```
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.array([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)], dtype=object)
```

Or even more clean:

```
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me present you two options using numpy module and loops.

```
import numpy as np

print("Using numpy module:")
x = np.array([1,5,2])
y = np.array([7,4,1])

sum = x + y
subtract = x - y
mult = x * y
div = x / y

print("Sum: {}".format(sum))
print("Subtraction: {}".format(subtract))
print("Multiplication: {}".format(mult))
print("Division: {}".format(div))

print("----------------------------------------")

print("Using for loops:")

x = [1,5,2]
y = [7,4,1]

sum = []
subtract = []
mult =[]
div = []

for i,j in zip(x,y):
    sum.append(i+j)
    subtract.append(i-j)
    mult.append(i*j)
    div.append(i/j)


print(sum)
print(subtract)
print(mult)
print(div)
```